# mongodb+aggregation - убрать в документе верхний уровень

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

У меня есть коллекция документов по типу:

```
{fields:{_id:1, f1:10, f2:"репа", f3:200}, computedFields:{id:1}},
{fields:{_id:2, f1:10, f2:"репа", f3:200}, computedFields:{id:2}},
...
```

**Внутри курсора (pipeline) мне нужно преобразовать каждый документ к виду:**

```
{_id:1, f1:10, f2:"репа", f3:200, id:1},
{_id:2, f1:10, f2:"репа", f3:200, id:2},
...
```

Т.е. нужно избавиться от верхнего уровня, оставив нижний

**Прошу подсказать, как это сделать**

Comment: Если вы не хотите изменить структуру документы то вам нужно использовать  `mapReduce` посколько вы не знаете название все поля.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку `fields` имеют свои уникальные идентификаторы, можно воспользоваться методом [`distinct`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#db.collection.distinct):

```
SomeModel.distinct("fields")
```

Этот код вернет список **уникальных** объектов `fields` из всех объектов коллекции `SomeModel`. Если вам нужны результаты с повторениями, то `distinct` тут не поможет.

Answer (score -1):

попробуй это：

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      array: {
        $concatArrays: [
          {
            $objectToArray: "$fields"
          },
          {
            $objectToArray: "$computedFields"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: "$array"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: прости， сейчас должен роботать